# How do I prevent a scroll view from letting a user (temporarily) scroll a UIScrollView out of it's content area?

Tags: ios, xcode

UIScroll view lets me declared a scrollable area when I have too much content for one page.  Strangely, the scroll view in question behaves as desired in the X-axis, with no scrolling whatsoever allowed.  Unfortunately, the Y axis -- where scrolling is necessary -- doesn't 'clip' the allowed scroll area to the content size.  The user can scroll outside of the content size, and only after they let go does scroll view 'bounce' back to the allowed zone.

I want to prevent the user from scrolling further up than there is content to view (down doesn't bother me) because it looks 'wrong' to have the header at the top of the scroll view pull down, leaving the regular background behind it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are making your `UIScrollView` in interface this is as simple as deselecting the

> "Bounces, Bounces Horizontally, and Bounces Vertically"

check boxes in your scrollView's attributes. If you are designing the `UIScrollView` in code you can add this.

```
self.textView.alwaysBounceHorizontal = NO;
self.textView.alwaysBounceVertical = NO;
self.textView.bounces = NO;
```

Comment: Ah, thanks.  I take it there's no way to separate 'top' from 'bottom' for enabling bouncing?  (No biggie if not, just...  seems like an odd omission)

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, at least not that I know of. I mean anythings possible, but I honestly think it would be WAY more trouble than it would be worth.

Comment: Agreed: WAY more trouble than it's worth to try and implement it myself.  Just odd that apple didn't implement it.